# i am getting this error: Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

Hi i am working on cloudformation template, my aim is to create High availability auto scaling group in ECS but i am getting this error. Events screenshot and code screenshot added. If u want any requirements ready to give

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbG6s.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3CJe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdBFW.png)